# Google Apps Script Initial form submit v. form edits

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google form that logs all of the submitted info into a template on `Google Drive` .  The `onFormSubmit` trigger works flawlessly any time that anyone creates a new form entry .

However, if someone goes in and edits an entry the `onFormSubmit` trigger does not trip at all.

I want to avoid doing this on any sort of SpreadSheet `onChange()` or that route.

Is there an `onFormSubmit()` for edits to the original submission?

Answer (score 0):

The following entry ([Issue 2969: On Submit trigger is not working when form response is edited](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2969)) in the issue tracker for Google Apps Script can clarify the issue.

> The form submit event in Google Forms and the one in Google Sheets work differently. For legacy reasons an edit doesn't trigger the form submit event in Sheets, but as you've found it does in Forms.
>   **Status:** WorkingAsIntended